# Differentiable function in point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For what value of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ function :
$f(x):=\begin{cases} a &\text{dla } x \in \mathbb{Q}\\x^2+ax+a &\text{dla } x \in \mathbb{R \setminus Q} \end{cases}$

is  differentiable at least one point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more general set-up for this kind of questions is the following:

Let $g, h \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be two functions and define $$f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) ,\text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
h(x), \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}.
 \end{cases}$$

If $g$ and $h$ are continuous functions, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $g(x_0) = h(x_0)$.

If $g$ and $h$ are differentiable functions, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if $g(x_0)= h(x_0)$ and $g'(x_0) = h'(x_0)$. [and so on ...]

For the current problem, $g(x) = a$ (constant function) and $h(x) = x^2+ax+a$.

Comment: I think, that for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ function is differentiable. Because, i have $x^2+(a-2)x-a=0$ and $\Delta=a^2+4$

Comment: I made a mistake. I know. Thanks you very muchy.